# invisible, unawarded upvote

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

For an [answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68879/formula-for-working-out-the-number-of-dice-combinations-resulting-in-a-given-valu/68894#68894) I appear to have gotten 1 upvote, my reputation page shows an upvote at 22:51:04, but no points (just a blank where points usually show). I can find no reason why the points aren't showing up.Totaling the points for yesterday, the invisible points are also unawarded points.

Is there an explanation I am missing, or is something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your reputation tab on your user page it looks like you are at the +200 per day rep cap.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: ...and he's just gotten the Mortarboard badge... :)

Comment: Aha! I have 230 because 30 are from acceptances. I would have not been as concerned if it stopped at 200, but it stopped at 230, which is an odd number for a cap.  Thanks.

Comment: @robjohn: Neither bonuses for accepted answers nor bounties collected count towards the cap.