# Upvotes without getting the points (with 115 daily rep). Bounty related?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, daily-reputation-limit

Sorry for a technical question (I've already seen the answers to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9531/73025) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3049/73025)). Though I have earned 200 daily rep already, I have also set a 100 points bounty, so that somehow the counter stopped at 115. Is that normal? If yes, how does it count wrt certain badges like Mortarboard? (I already have this one).

One more question: it happened to me several times to get >200 points daily - how was that possible with the upper bound?

Comment: Related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [How does proposing a bounty affect the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51257)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get at most 200 points from upvotes in any single day. If on the same day you give a bounty (which you did), or lose points to downvotes, etc — this does not matter. The cap is applied to your *income* from upvotes, not to your *net profit*.

Other sources of income, such as bounties and +15 from accepts, are not capped. They make it possible to earn more than 200 points in a day.

`Mortarboard` is awarded only once, but you still have the `Epic` and `Legendary` badges to work toward. These badges work differently from the reputation cap. In order for a day to count toward the badge, you should have a *net profit* of 200 points or more in that day (excluding association bonuses). That is, if your net profit today is 140, this day will not move you toward  the `Epic` and  `Legendary` badges, even though you capped.

Source: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Comment: Excellent answer!